# because + gerund

Tags: gerunds

Can someone tell me why because is followed by a gerund? I've also come across gerunds used after "that". Neither of these instances fall under any of the rules governing gerund use--after certain verbs, prepositions and as subjects--because is a conjunction and that is an adverb. It would be helpful to know as I'm teaching gerunds and infinitives right now. Thanks.

Comment: Because it's not always followed by a gerund (as I deliberately demonstrated by how I started this sentence), you need to clarify your question. Please provide at least one example sentence that shows what you're asking about, and how you think it should be phrased instead.

Comment: Okay, for example, He didn't take the road, because going that way would be longer. I know because isn't always followed by a gerund. Neither are prepositions. But prepositions are listed among the parts of speech that take a gerund after them but conjunctions--which is what because is--are not. I'd like to know if anyone can explain this.

Comment: In your example, _because_ doesn't govern the gerund. _Because_ takes a whole finite clause, of which the subject is the gerund clause _going that way_.

Comment: To follow up on the previous comment, in the example used the gerund could be governed by *because* if the nouns were changed and you used a new sense of the word: *He didn't take the highway because **walking**.* However, that's debatable because *walking* is actually an elided form of *he was walking*, which, if expanded, would mean that *because* is actually followed by *he* from a semantic point of view. (In short, it's a bit of a cheat.)

Comment: However, here's an example that might be acceptable: *In his effort to stay fit, he frequently travelled on foot, because walking was better than driving.* But I'm not sure if the fact that a gerund follows *because* in that example is really notable.